# Dynamic insert statement fails on SQL server 2005, however work fine on SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure in which it dynamically generate separate SQL insert statement inside each cursor iteration. However once I run this on SQL Server 2005, it fails but run without failing on SQL Server 2008 R2. I noted that reason for failing on 2005 is single quote appeared in the varchar column. But same can be observed on 2008 R2 but it ignores insert statement which has single quote in it and continue with rest of the statements. I wonder why SQL Server 2008 R2 ignores fail insert statement.

```
SELECT @sqlCommand = 'INSERT INTO INVOICE_DETAILS(unique_no, invoice_no, item_code, description, qty, selling_price, cost, created_date, created_user_id, last_modified_user, last_modified_date)
        VALUES ('+ @unique_no + ','''+ @invoice_no + ''','''',''' + @desc + ''',' + @qty + ',' + @selling_price + ',' + @cost + ',GETDATE(),' + @user_id + ',' + @user_id + ',GETDATE())'

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

Sample print @sqlCommand as follows;

```
INSERT INTO INVOICE_DETAILS(unique_no, invoice_no, item_code, description, qty, selling_price, cost, created_date, created_user_id, last_modified_user, last_modified_date)
        VALUES (2316,'CGB880228','Bickiepeg's Teething Biscuits',12,25.36,25.00,GETDATE(),162,162,GETDATE())
```

Anyone knows reason why SQL Server 2008 R2 ignore fail insert statement and continue with rest of insert statements?

Comment: above print query also not working in 2008 and 2012 because one special character coming between query  `'Bickiepeg's `

Comment: but when it comes to dynamic query, it works on 2008 R2. Means that 2008 R2 ignores the insert statements with single quote and jump to next insert statements without breaking the while loop. I tested adding series of insert statements, one with single quote among, it fails both versions. But this issue is with dynamic query.

Comment: Don't build  query with baked in variables in sql, use params and pass parameters explicitly [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). Also user can compromise your code using SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't concatenate string like you did, because user can comprise your code with SQL Injection attack.

Pass parameters explicitly [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

```
SELECT 
   @sqlCommand =
   N'INSERT INTO INVOICE_DETAILS(unique_no, invoice_no, item_code, description, qty, selling_price, cost, created_date, created_user_id, last_modified_user, last_modified_date)
     VALUES (@unique_no, @invoice_no, @desc, @qty, @selling_price, @cost, @user_id, @user_id,GETDATE())'

DECLARE @param_list NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @param_list = N'@unique_no type,
                    (...)
                    @user_id type';      


EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
     @sqlCommand,
     @param_list,
     @unique_no,
     (...)
     @user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. This could greatly help me to resolve issue.